# File Connector use a File Pattern with the list operation

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule4, mule-esb, mule-connector

How can I filter the file list in 2 types of files (CSV, XML) just files that has those extensions with a filepattern?

Comment: Which version of Mule are you using?

Comment: is the version 4.3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `<file:matcher>` element as mentioned in the [documentation examples](https://docs.mulesoft.com/file-connector/1.3/file-list#filter-files-by-matching-criteria).

Example:

```
<file:list path="/somepath">
    <file:matcher filenamePattern="*.{csv,xml}" />
</file:list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find sample below

```
<file:config name="File_Config" doc:name="File Config" doc:id="7f86b325-8109-4447-8205-f96ecd87434d" />

<flow name="tempFlow" doc:id="0f9cf686-a0f4-45d0-8a85-864468099c07">
  <file:list doc:name="List" doc:id="2e122fad-5c98-47d3-acfc-3f014b8aee87" config-ref="File_Config" directoryPath="/dir/" matcher="csv, xml"/>
</flow>
```